# text strip nonetype error while scraping information using Selenium Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I have ask a kind similar question but still it does not solve this problem. The problem is I want to **scrape** the price information and the discount information from a website with HTML code below:

Price HTML code (information wish to **scrape**: NOW RM 168.90):

```
<span class="b-catalogList__itmPriceBox itm-priceBox fsm txtDark">
  <span class="b-catalogList__itmPrice old">RM 179.00</span>
  <span class="b-catalogList__itmPrice special">NOW RM 168.90</span><div class="evergreen- 
  rectangle "></div>
</span>
```

Discount HTML code (information wish to **scrape** : 6% OFF):

```
<div class="b-catalogList__itmPriceDiscountTag">
   <div class="discountTag__Top">
      <div class="discountTag__PercentText withoutUpTo">6% OFF</div> 
  </div>
      <div class="discountTag__Bottom"></div> 
</div>
```

**Its all went SUCCEED when I ran by this below code BY BLOCK**; which given the output that I want;

```
p_price = card.select_one('.b-catalogList__itmPrice old, span:nth-of-type(3) .special').text
print(p_price)
```

and

```
pdisc = card.find("div", "discountTag__Top").text.strip()
print(pdisc)
```

**BUT, BUT, as I merge the code together into a single code,**

```
!pip install selenium 
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def get_url(product):
    product = product.replace(' ', '+')
    template_new = "https://www.zalora.com.my/"
    
    # default search will lead to this
    if product ==  "shirt" or product == "hoodies":
        template = template_new + "men/clothing/{}"
    elif product == "pants":
        template = template_new + "kids/clothing/{}-leggings"
    
    
    
    url = template.format(product)
    return url

def get_info(card):
    
    pbrand = card.find('span', "brand-name").text.strip()
    
    pname = card.find('em', 'b-catalogList__itmTitle fss').text
    
    # PRICE (problem)
    p_price = card.select_one('.b-catalogList__itmPrice old, span:nth-of-type(3) .special').text
    #pprice = p_price.replace("NOW", "")
    
    # DISCOUNT (problem)
    pdisc = card.find("div", "discountTag__PercentText withoutUpTo").text.strip()
    
    pimage = card.find("img", "b-catalogList__itm-img b-catalogList__itm-img--hovered")['src']
    
    p_href = card.a['href']
    phref = "https://www.zalora.com.my/" + p_href
    
    info = (pname, pbrand, p_price, pdisc, pimage, phref)
    
    return info 

def main(product):
    
    records = []
    url = get_url(product)
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)
    
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)
    
    # AUTO-SCROLLING 
    # -- make the parsing time of python is equivalent to the web 
    temp_height=0
 
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1000)")
        time.sleep(5)
        check_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop;")
        if check_height==temp_height:
            break
        temp_height=check_height
    
    time.sleep(5)
    # AUTO-SCROLL end
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    cards = soup.find_all("li", "b-catalogList__itm hasOverlay unit size1of3")
    
    for allproduct in cards:
        productDetails = get_info(allproduct)
        records.append(productDetails)
        
    col = ['Name', 'Brand', 'Price', 'Discount', 'Image', 'Link']
        
    all_product = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=col)
    
    all_product.to_csv('D:\\ZALORA-{}.csv'.format(product))
```

and ran the code with `main("pants")`, the output went error with

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f3c09d962c07> in <module>
----> 1 main("pants")

<ipython-input-5-020f8a1be3a7> in main(product)
     72 
     73     for allproduct in cards:
---> 74         productDetails = get_info(allproduct)
     75         records.append(productDetails)
     76 

<ipython-input-5-020f8a1be3a7> in get_info(card)
     27 
     28     # PRICE (problem)
---> 29     p_price = card.select_one('.b-catalogList__itmPrice old, span:nth-of-type(3) .special').text
     30     #pprice = p_price.replace("NOW", "")
     31 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I have changed a lot of different code on the price and the discount, but its all about the `.text` or `.text.strip()` that caused the problem. I dont know **why it works when running by block** but **went wrong went running in a single code**. Please help me.

Comment: When running your code it raises an error:`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'template' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @MendelG mine works well on the url part which has the template. It raise error on the price part.